# How to get a specific constructor that matches an Interface?

Tags: c#, reflection

So playing with my own test Dependency Injector class. (yeah tons out there but this is just for fun)

Works decent but I don't know how to get the correct constructor based on the Interface passed in.

```
internal class DiContainer
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, RegistryRecord> registry = new Dictionary<Type, RegistryRecord>();

    private static DiContainer instance;

    private DiContainer()
    {
    }

    public static DiContainer GetInstance()
    {
        return instance ??= new DiContainer();
    }

    public void Register<T, C>() where C : class, T
    {
        registry.Add(typeof(T), new RegistryRecord
        {
            InterfaceType = typeof(T),
            ConcreteType = typeof(C),
            IsSingleTon = false
        });
    }

    public void Register<C>() where C : class
    {
        Register(typeof(C));
    }

    public void Register(Type t)
    {
        registry.Add(t, new RegistryRecord
        {
            InterfaceType = t,
            ConcreteType = t,
            IsSingleTon = false
        });
    }

    public void RegisterSingleton<T, C>(C instance = null) where C : class, T
    {
        registry.Add(typeof(T), new RegistryRecord
        {
            InterfaceType = typeof(T),
            ConcreteType = typeof(C),
            IsSingleTon = true,
            Instance = instance
        });
    }

    public T Get<T>()
    {
        return (T) Get(typeof(T));
    }

    
    public object Get(Type t)
    {
        ConstructorInfo constructor;

        RegistryRecord r = null;

        if (t.IsInterface && registry.ContainsKey(t))
        {
            r = registry[t];

            if (r.IsSingleTon && r.Instance != null) return r.Instance;

            constructor = r.ConcreteType.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)[0];
        }
        else
        {
            //todo how do we select the correct constructor?
            constructor = t.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)[0];
        }

        var parameters = constructor.GetParameters();

        //recurse to build dependency chain
        var objects = parameters.Select(parameter => Get(parameter.ParameterType)).ToList();

        var obj = constructor.Invoke(objects.ToArray());

        if (r != null && r.IsSingleTon)
        {
            r.Instance = obj;
        }

        return obj;
    }

}


internal class RegistryRecord
{
    public Type InterfaceType { get; set; }
    public Type ConcreteType { get; set; }
    public object Instance { get; set; }
    public bool IsSingleTon { get; set; }

}
```

So the problem is

```
constructor = t.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)[0];
```

I am just assuming the first constructor which is awful. But I have the definition of the interface I could be using.

How do I get the parameters of my interface and check them against the constructor?

Would like to select a constructor that matches the interface, or at least partially matches optimally.

**edit**

An example

```
using System;

namespace DITest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var di = DiContainer.GetInstance();

            //Register classes / interfaces
            di.Register<IPhoneResolver, PhoneResolver>();
            di.Register<Customer>();

            //Get class where dependency should be injected
            var x = di.Get<Customer>();

            Console.WriteLine(x.resolver.Name);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        //Remove this and everything is ok. Because we select the first one not the right one
        public Customer()
        {
        }

        public Customer(IPhoneResolver resolver)
        {
            this.resolver = resolver;
        }

        public IPhoneResolver resolver { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IPhoneResolver
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        bool DoesSomething();
    }

    public class PhoneResolver : IPhoneResolver
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "test";

        public bool DoesSomething()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

So because the first constructor is null there is an issue.

I need a way to resolve the correct constructor. I have the interface via the RegistryRecord and (type) InterfaceType. I need to find a way to get a constructor that matches that types parameters.

Comment: Not sure I get this -- an interface as implemented by a class wouldn't affect its constructor(s). Or do you mean selecting one constructor, maybe among several, which has that interface in its signature -- as in `public MyClass(IMyInterface m) {....}`?

Comment: Not sure I get this either.  How would you dynamically know what arguments to give a constructor?  Your `Get` method doesn't take in any arguments to give a constructor.  You appear to be just constructing the default values of all types that would be in a constructor, but how do you know this is the appropriate input to the constructor you found?  I think you should just write code that looks for the parameterless constructor.  (Or just use `Activator.CreateInstance(type)`.)

Comment: So the RegistryRecord is accessible, it has an InterfaceType property that would contain the type. So ICustomer would be in there. It also has the concrete type of Customer. I want to create a Customer object with a constructor that matches ICustomer.

Comment: You have to check every parameter in the ctor for a match. See the code `MatchesArgumentTypes` here as an example https://github.com/Capgemini/Cauldron/blob/master/Shared/Cauldron.Activator/Reflection/ExtensionsReflection.cs

Comment: What do you mean by "a constructor that matches ICustomer"?  Do you mean a constructor for the Customer class that has as many arguments as ICustomer has properties? Or the Customer constructor takes in an ICustomer as the sole argument?  I still think parameterless is the way to go here.  Again, I don't know where you hope to get the _values_ for all these parameters from.  If your plan was to just use default values for all types in a constructor, I don't see how that's better than just using a parameterless constructor.  If you think it's important, show more code to explain.

Comment: If I have a class of Customer and it accepts an ILogger as a parameter. I want to be able to create the Customer class and inject an ILogger in there. So I can get the Ilogger but I need to be able to determine which constructor is asking for an ILogger. Right now I'm just calling the first one, so if it's empty that would fail.

Comment: That helps explain what you're trying to achieve; might be worth putting this (with more code samples) into the question.  The code you've written feels almost too generic, then.  For example, you say you can get an instance of ILogger, but I don't see how you would know you even need to inject one. There are always other methods, such as checking if your Type t implements an ISupportLogging interface, then casting to the interface and calling a method to set the logger.  I guess it's not clear how generic or specific you want the `Get` method to be, so more context in the question would help.

Comment: You can use System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[] GetParameters on each constructorinfo (removing the [0]). Then you can compare the types to your registration and throw an exception when you can't find a constructor or when you find many

Comment: Mono - do you have an example you could link?

Comment: I would make it an answer as I'm sure that is the way to go.